# what's the real cardinality constrained regularization instead of L0 regularization?

Tags: regression, regularization

In a regression problem, with coefficient $w$, there are some use cases that wish to constrain the cardinality of $w$.

And a popular choice is to use the $L_0$ norm. Namely $||w||_0 \leq k$ . I'm a bit confused about the usage of the $L_0$ norm since it's only counting non-zero terms in $w$. Which is not strictly reducing the cardinality.

A counter example would be: between $w_1 = (2, 2, 0, 0, 0)$ and $w_2 = (2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$. the $L_0$ norm would consider the "cardinality" of $w_1$ as 2. while $w_2$ has "cardinality" 5.  Which is obviously false, as cadinality of $w_2$ is 1.

My question is, what kind of regularization does the correct cardinality reducing job?

The counterexample is really to exaggerate the difference between cardinality and none-zero elements. And also to bring more context to the problem, my predictors/features are all binary $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: I find it very confusing to require that all parameter estimates be identical (are predictors even on a comparable scale?) and to refer to this as "a cardinality of 1". If you are only looking at very low "cardinalities" in this sense, you could do this for cardinality 1 by considering a simple linear regression on the sum of your original predictors, for cardinality 2 by looking at all possible regressions where your original predictors are summed into two resulting regressors and so forth. In general, for cardinality $c$ and $k$ original predictors, there are $c^k$ models to check.

Comment: that example is just to exaggerate the difference between the definition of cardinalities and none zero elements.  and as regularization typically does is to encourage the coeffs to have certain properties instead of finding the optimal, wondering if there is any functional form to express that property.

Comment: and in my settings, all predictors are binary $\{0, 1\}$. @StephanKolassa

Comment: The obvious answer is to use a multiple of the cardinality as the penalty term.  That probably doesn't help you solve your original problem, though, because finding a solution remains the same combinatorial problem--the penalty is a decidedly non-continuous, non-convex function of the parameters.  Moreover, the number of combinatorial patterns grows very fast: it equals the number of partitions of $k.$